# How do I concatenate a string literal of my cell to a string of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I am trying to make life easier for myself by organising my teaching materials for private tutees of mine from various subjects/educational levels in google spreadsheets.

I want to know how I can take a string literal such as "Paper " and concatenate it to the string of characters as they appear in another cell using a formula.

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It looks like you want the `&` operator

I'm not quite clear which thing you are concatenating to which in the question; however, you can do either

```
=$BJ$2 & "24"
```

or

```
=$BJ$2 & BH1
```

or

```
="Paper" & BH1
```

assuming you are on row 2 and the number is on row 1 (the `$` locks the cell so that it doesn't change when copying/pasting).

Here's an example with a test spreadsheet:
[image: example]

Comment: & this is why SE is so great, cheers

Comment: & worked great !

Comment: @NextlnLine perfect!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's an alternative option.

For a similar case, I used `Array Formula` and `SUBSTITUTE` hack. It makes formulas readable and helps with more complex joins. I found this option in [this article](https://blog.coupler.io/merge-cells-google-sheets/). It worked smoothly.

I hope it'll help you too